# CAD software on Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation

I want to use some free CAD software on ubuntu.  That allows me to draw lines and shapes using exact metrics (e.g. cm) or using a scale (e.g. m, km).  Is there anything like the aforementioned that I can use.  Currently I have been using Gimp and Open Office but they are not suitable for my use.

Comment: Please google: "linux cad software"